# WPF focus DataGrid during GotFocus event of another control problem

Tags: c#, wpf, events, focus

According to the asnwer to [Event for when KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation Cycle occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979030/event-for-when-keyboardnavigation-tabnavigation-cycle-occurs), the go-to solution is to add invisible control as last TabIndex of a Detail focus scope, handling `GotFocus()` on this dummy element. As part of handling this 'event' I would like to move focus back to master grid `MasterDG.Focus()`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="MasterDG" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"/>
    <StackPanel Name="Detail" Grid.Row="1"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
        <Control Name="DummyControl" 
                 GotFocus="DummyControl_GotFocus"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Event handler

```
private void DummyControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Save(); //save when done editing last element of detail
    MasterDG.Focus();
}
```

However this causes not only `MasterDG` to be focused but also **enter Edit mode** on current cell and **insert** `\t` character overwriting any cell content. How can I fix the issue?
*Note the actual contents of Detail are dynamically generated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround would be to call `Focus()` in the next dispatcher cycle:

```
private void DummyControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Save(); //save when done editing last element of detail
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MasterDG.Focus()));
}
```

Comment: Good idea - since it is GUI, I could probably get away with it. Still figguring out whether it could be adapeted to MVVM + IsFocused attached property though. Probably not.